# Create Facebook ad to open in an external browser from app

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I am creating a facebook ad and the client needs to open that ad in a new tab so that the camera is operational outside the "WebView". I am unable to find any option that uses that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would be great if possible. A solution would be to try Google Ads